# My API request works but I can't access the content

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, use-effect, use-state

I made a API request:

```
const [animes, setAnimes] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get("https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/38000/characters")
        .then((response) => {
            setAnimes(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);
```

when I do [console.log(animes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYP1J.jpg) I receive the data with a array of 76 items. But, when I do:

```
<div className="container">
                {!!animes.length &&
                    animes?.slice(0, 9).map((anime, index) => {
                        return (
                            <img
                                key={index}
                                src={anime.image_url}
                                alt={anime.name}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
            </div>
```

I can't get the img and the alt. The console.log result is a object with a array inside. But if I use "setAnimes(response.data.data)" I receive just the array and even with this I can't get the content.

If I console.log(setAnimes) I receive this:

```
function dispatchSetState(fiber, queue, action) {
{
if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
  error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 
  'second callback argument. To execute a side effect after ' + 'rendering, declare it 
  in the component body with useEffect().');
  }
 }

 var lane = requestUpdateLane(fiber);
 var update = {
 lane: lane,
 action: action,
 hasEagerState: false,
 eagerState: null,
 next: null
 };
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the anime object doesn't contain `image_url` or `name` properties.

It just contains these properties

1. character: Object
2. role: string
3. voice_actors: Array

Check console.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-hopper-ytxkvc

Comment: But inside  1. character: object I have images and inside images have jpg and webp. Inside the both I have "image_url". Why I can't access this property?

Comment: So, you have to access it by `object.property`, I just update the codesandbox to make it working with jpg image_url, please check.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for **image_url** and **name** in the wrong object.

use `anime.character.images.jpg.image_url` and `anime.character.name` to refer to correct
properties

Comment: This worked!!! Thanks!! In the image case I needed to go deeper. Like {anime.character.images.webp.image_url}